# $\{e^{ik}\mid k\in \Bbb N\}$ is dense in $S^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I wanted to {$e^{ik}|k\in N$} Is dense in $S^1$
My Attempt:

On the contrary, assume that it is not dense in $S^1$.
So there exists a point in $S^1$ which is not a limit point, say $e^it $ for some $t\in R$
That means $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that $\forall k\in N ,|e^{ik}-e^{it}|>\epsilon $ that is
$|e^{i(k-t)}-1|>\epsilon $
I was expecting some contradiction to occur.
But I am not able to see.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you could try to show that $k \mod 2 \pi$ is dense in $[0,2 \pi]$?

Comment: Your proof needs to use that $2\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: That is an irrational statement.

Answer (score 0):

As already in the comments indicated, you have to use that $\pi$ is irrational. The key tool here is [Kronecker's Approximation Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html). The proof of Kronecker's Approximation Theorem is quite simple (it is an application of the pigeonhole-principle), but there are no 'simple' proofs of the irrationality of $\pi$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) for more details.